# Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding

Tags: google-play

I have the same issue with KEY export for Google play.

Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding

I try this, and looks like worked.

1. download bcprov-jdk18on-176.jar
   https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html#LATEST
2. use
   java -cp **bcprov-jdk18on-176.jar**:pepk.jar **com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool** --keystore=**KEYSTORE** --alias=**ALIAS** --output=**output.zip** --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=**encryption_public_key.pem**

This is the name of main class

1. xtract the contents of the pepk.jar file:
   jar xf pepk.jar
2. Navigate to the extracted META-INF directory and open the MANIFEST.MF file in a text editor.
   Look for a line starting with Main-Class:, followed by the name of the main class. It might look something like this:
   **com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool**